# Should I always call close of jedis instance at the end of business logic?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jedis

I`m using jedis as the with spring boot for redis connection.

The jedis pool is configured as follow:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(JedisPool.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(JedisProperties.class)
public class JedisAutoConfiguration {
    private JedisProperties jedisProperties;
    
    public JedisAutoConfiguration(JedisProperties jedisProperties) {
        this.jedisProperties = jedisProperties;
    }
    
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(JedisPool.class)
    public JedisPool jedisPool() {
        
        JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        poolConfig.setMaxIdle(jedisProperties.getPool().getMaxIdle());
        poolConfig.setMaxTotal(jedisProperties.getPool().getMaxTotal());
        poolConfig.setMaxWaitMillis(jedisProperties.getPool().getMaxWaitMillis() * 1000);
        
        JedisPool jedisPool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, jedisProperties.getHost(), jedisProperties.getPort(),
                jedisProperties.getTimeout()*1000, jedisProperties.getPassword(), 0);
        return jedisPool;
    }
}
```

Each time when I need to connect to the redis, I would rent a resource from jedis pool:

```
@Service
public class UserService   {

    
    @Autowired
    private JedisPool jedisPool;


    public User FindUserFromCache(Integer id){
        Jedis resource  = jedisPool.getResource()
        // business logic

        // resource.close()
    }

}
```

Question:

1.Should I return the resource to pool at the end of business logic? Could spring boot or java runtime handle this situation automatically?

2.If resource not closed then the resource would never return to the pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I return the resource to pool at the end of business logic?

Yes.

You can use Java's try-with-resources feature as well.

```
    try (Jedis resource  = jedisPool.getResource()) {
        // business logic
    }
```

> Could spring boot or java runtime handle this situation automatically?

JedisPool is base on Apache `commons-pool2` project which neither part of spring (boot) or core java. So these can't/don't handle this situation automatically.

> If resource not closed then the resource would never return to the pool?

To be precise, if resource is **not returned** then it would never be back to the pool. There are other ways to return the resource to the pool. But `close()` supposed to be user-friendly way.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of working directly with the Jedis connection pool, it would probably be preferable for you to work with **RedisTemplate**.

This way, you won't be bothered with with freeing Jedis connection resources in the business logic code. Meaning better abstraction.

Also, you'll be able to change in future the driver from "Jedis" to the newer "Lettuce" without touching your business logic.

See more here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:template